Is the ESP32 able to subscribe to more than 2 topics of an MQTT Broker?
I'm doing an MQTT library for a project using the Espressif ID, and when I try to subscribe to more than 2 topics with one ESP32 i get the following error:
[1B][0;31mE (2594) mqtt_client: Subscribe message cannot be created[1B][0m
Is there any configuration that I need to change/add on the client handler?
esp_mqtt_client_config_t cfg = {
    .broker.address.hostname = ip,
    .broker.address.port = port,
    .broker.address.transport = MQTT_TRANSPORT_OVER_TCP,
    .credentials.set_null_client_id = true,
    .session.protocol_ver = MQTT_PROTOCOL_V_3_1_1,
    .task.priority = 1,
    .task.stack_size = 4096,
    .buffer.size = 32,
    .buffer.out_size = 32
};

I'll leave here the MQTT Event Handler and the topics I'm trying to subscribe:
#define NUM_OF_TOPICS (uint8_t)(3)
static const char* topics[NUM_OF_TOPICS] = {"esp1/dev1", "esp1/dev2", "esp1/dev3"};

static void mqttEventHandler(void* args, esp_event_base_t base, int32_t id, void* data) {
    static uint8_t retry = MQTT_MAX_RETRY;
    esp_mqtt_event_handle_t event = (esp_mqtt_event_handle_t)data;
    esp_mqtt_client_handle_t client = event->client;

    switch ((esp_mqtt_event_id_t)id) {
    case MQTT_EVENT_CONNECTED:
        retry = MQTT_MAX_RETRY;

        esp_mqtt_topic_t list[NUM_OF_TOPICS];
        for (uint8_t t = 0; t < NUM_OF_TOPICS; t++) {
            list[t].filter = topics[t];
            list[t].qos = 2;
        }
        esp_mqtt_client_subscribe_multiple(client, list, NUM_OF_TOPICS);

        break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_DISCONNECTED:
        if (--retry) {
            esp_mqtt_client_start(client);
        }
        break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_SUBSCRIBED:
        printf("[mqtt] Subscribed to all topics.\n");
        break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED:
        printf("[mqtt] Published a message.\n");
        break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_DATA:
        printf("[mqtt] Received data -> %.*s\n", event->data_len, event->data);
        printf("[mqtt] @ topic -> %.*s\n", event->topic_len, event->topic);
        // User code begin



        // User code end
        memset(event->topic, '\0', event->topic_len);
        memset(event->data, '\0', event->data_len);
        break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_BEFORE_CONNECT:
        printf("[mqtt] Starting connection...\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("[mqtt] Undefined event: %d\n", (uint8_t)id);
        break;
    }
}

I tried to change the list of topics to subscribe to dynamic memory, expecting the problem to be the memory allocation for the list of topics, but the same error occurred.

Your 3 topics add up to 27 bytes. These need to be sent, along with a header, length for each topic, QOS values etc - this is not all going to fit into the 32 byte buffer (.buffer.out_size) you configured.

@Gerhardh, thx for the hint. This was a typo

@xicobski Depending on the circumstances of your project (message size, certificate exchanges, etc.) , I would recommend to set your buffer.size to several kilobyte (n * 1024) and the buffer.out_size to several kilobyte (n * 1024). Modify your task.stack_size accordingly
